# Using F# JsonProvider within a portable class library fails

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm trying to use the JsonProvider and I'm getting the following error when I call a function on it:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in PortableLibrary1.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$PortableLibrary1>.$PortableLibrary1' threw an exception.
```

I have a basic console application as follows:

```
module Pinit =
   open FSharp.Data

   type JsonT = JsonProvider<"""..\myFile.json""">
   let doc = JsonT.Load("""..\nyFile.json""")
   let result = doc.GeneratedAt

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" Pinit.doc.GeneratedAt
    0
```

When run within the ConsoleApplication it all works as expected.
If I create an F# Portable Class library as follows:

```
module Pinit =
   open FSharp.Data

   type JsonT = JsonProvider<"""..\myFile.json""">
   let doc = JsonT.Load("""..\nyFile.json""")
   let result = doc.GeneratedAt
```

Create another Console Application and reference that Portable Class Library and call the code as follows:

```
open PortableLibrary1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" Pinit.result
    0
```

When I run the program then it generates the exception defined above:

I'm suspecting it's because of the versions of FSharp.Core but was wondering whether I was doing something wrong or whether there was a way to get this to work?

Versions:

```
-- ConsoleApplication --
FSharp.Core = 4.3.1.0

-- PortableClassLibrary --
FSharp.Core = 3.3.1.0
FSharp.Data = NuGet Version: 2.0.0
```

Comment: What's `Pinit.result`?

Comment: I've updated my question with the assignment to Pinit.result.  It's just the result of an assignment from the JsonProvider.  In this case it happens to be a System.DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let bindings are compiled into static members, and in .NET when you have an exception in a static initializer the real exception is masqueraded.

If you turn that into a function call by changing to `let result() = doc.GeneratedAt` and `printfn "%A" (Pinit.result())` you'll get the real exception:

```
Only web locations are supported
```

Portable profiles don't support accessing the file system. So inside the PCL you can either have web urls or load manually from an embedded resource. See here for an example: https://github.com/ovatsus/Apps/blob/master/Trains/Stations.fs#L65. Or you can load the file with `File.ReadAllText` in the console project and pass it to the PCL.

This was with a Portable Profile (Legacy) project, which is Profile 47 (and FSharp.Core 2.3.6.0). I then also tested with a Portable Profile project, which is Profile 7 (and FSharp.Core 3.3), and noticed it's not working correctly, it's giving this exception instead

```
Method not found: 'FSharp.Data.Runtime.JsonValueOptionAndPath FSharp.Data.Runtime.JsonRuntime.TryGetPropertyUnpackedWithPath(FSharp.Data.Runtime.IJsonDocument, System.String)'.
```

I created a github issue to track that: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/521

Comment: Thanks.  I've switched to using an Embedded Resource now but am unfortunately using Profile 7 so am hitting that Method Not Found exception you have mentioned above.