# Use FSharp.Data in a Class library project or Test project

Tags: f#, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I am trying to use the FSharp.Data library in a F# class library project (Not portable class. I am getting this error:

> Test 'Test1' failed:
>     OneTimeSetUp: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found:
>   'FSharp.Data.CsvFile FSharp.Data.CsvFile.Load(System.String,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<System.String>,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<Boolean>,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1)'.

I googled the error and found a couple of the similar posts like this one

[Using F# JsonProvider within a portable class library fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364717/using-f-jsonprovider-within-a-portable-class-library-fails)

but i am not in a portable class library just a normal class library. also i get similar error if i want to use the FSharp.Data in a F# unit test project.

Any advise will be appreciated.

FYI, I did install the the FSharp.Data in my Class library and test project which getting the error.

thanks

i have tried to target .net 4.5, 4.5.2 and F# 4.3.1 and 4.4 with FSharp.Data version 2.0.14 to 2.3.2 i have no luck with any of the combo.

Comment: All the problems I've seen with `MissingMethodException` have the same cause: assembly version conflicts. The solution is to add an assembly binding redirect in an `App.config` file. This is bound to be a duplicate, e.g. of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23389752/126014 There are [31 results here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bf%23%5d%20MissingMethodException).

Comment: Hi Mark, the link has the solution as "Apparently, FSharp.Data does not support PCL libraries using profile 7. After changing my PCL project profile to 47 everything works as expected". But I am not writing a Portable Class (rather a normal class library). I can call the offending F# Class library (uses the FSharp.Data) from a console program with no error.  I discovered this problem only during my Unit test of this F# Class library. Obviously my Test project is a Class library project. if it is the assembly is the issue, i would have got the same error in the console app.

Comment: Have you tried looking at one of the other [31 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bf%23%5d%20MissingMethodException) here? E.g. this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13846561/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann even when you manually set a reference to FSharp.Core 4.4.0, Visual Studio's test runner may pick up 4.3. I've been fighting this for the whole week. In the end I replaced references in my library and test projects with the FSharp.Core nuget package. Before that, the test runner wouldn't even find the tests

Comment: @casby in my case, I had to remove all manual references to FSharp.Core and use the FSharp.Core nuget package to ensure Visual Studio's test runner didn't load 4.3 (which is F# 3). Also check for missing redirects in your console app's app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark and Panagiotis. I am able to resolve this missing method problem with binding redirection. For those having similar issue, I did the followings:

1. add a new App.Config file to the test project.
2. rename the config file to whateverAssemblyName.dll.config
3. add the following lines (based on your F# version) to the config file:

   ```
      <runtime>
       <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity
             name="FSharp.Core"
             publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             culture="neutral"/>        
           <bindingRedirect
             oldVersion="0.0.0.0 - 4.4.0.0"
             newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   ```
4. make sure the config file is exported to when newer

I have to use TestDriven/test with nunit to launch the nunit window as the VS test explorer still can't discover the test case.